# What's wrong with my C++ Boost Spirit Grammar & Rules?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'm still pretty new to Boost and C++ (only a week in learning this).  With the great help from Sehe from my other post [Boost Spirit question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76375924/how-to-parse-code-definition-text-into-xml-structure-with-the-latest-boost-spiri) I'm trying to extend the Simple class to parse and accept more syntax but what I have doesn't seem to work right.

Currently, Simple class can handle this input:

```
Class Simple caption;
Class Simple columns "Column Name";
```

This is the original Simple class from the above link

```
using Id = std::string;
using Literal = std::string;
using Enum = std::vector<Id>;

struct Base {
    Id      id;
    Literal literal;
};

struct Simple : Base {
    Enum enumeration;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Simple, id, literal, enumeration);
```

And the grammar rule

```
id_ = raw[alpha >> *('_' | alnum)];
id_ = raw[alpha >> *('_' | alnum)];
literal_ = '"' > *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) > '"';
auto optlit = copy(literal_ | attr(std::string(" ")));

simple_ = lit("Simple") >> id_ >> optlit >> enum_;
enum_ = -(lit("enumeration") >> '(' >> (id_ % ',') > ')');
```

And the expected outcome is:

```
<class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>caption:caption</identifier>
      <literal>" "</literal>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>columns:columns</identifier>
      <literal>"Column Name"</literal>
    </simple>
  </class>
```

I'm trying to extend this rule so the Simple class can accept the following:

```
Class Simple caption;
Class Simple columns "Column Name";
Class Simple some_value datatype restriction;
Class Simple other_value Default 0;
```

And the new expected outcome should be:

```
<class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>caption:caption</identifier>
      <literal>" "</literal>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>columns:columns</identifier>
      <literal>"Column Name"</literal>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>some_value:some_value</identifier>
      <literal>" "</literal>
      <word>restriction</word>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>other_value:other_value</identifier>
      <literal>" "</literal>
      <default>
            <num>0</num>
      </default>
    </simple>
  </class>
```

This is what I did but Simple class did not correctly parse the above.

```
using Id = std::string;
using Literal = std::string;
using Datatype = std::string;
using Default = std::string;
using Enum = std::vector<Id>;

struct Base {
    Id      id;
    Literal literal;
};

struct Simple : Base {
    Enum enumeration;
    Datatype datatype;
        Default def;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Simple, id, literal, enumeration, datatype, def);
```

And for the grammar rule, I did this:

```
id_ = raw[alpha >> *('_' | alnum)];
id_ = raw[alpha >> *('_' | alnum)];
literal_ = '"' > *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) > '"';
auto optlit = copy(literal_ | attr(std::string(" ")));

simple_ = lit("Simple") >> id_ >> optlit >> (enum_ | datatype_ | default_);
enum_ = -(lit("enumeration") >> '(' >> (id_ % ',') > ')');
datatype_ = -(lit("datatype") >> id_);
default_ = -(lit("Default") >> alnum)

qi::rule<It, Ast::Simple(), Skipper>    simple_;
qi::rule<It, Ast::Enum(), Skipper>      enum_;
qi::rule<It, Ast::Datatype(), Skipper>  datatype_;
qi::rule<It, Ast::Default(), Skipper>  default_;
```

I keep getting parse error

```
 -> EXPECTED ";" in line:3
       Class Simple my_value datatype restriction;
                             ^--- here
```

It doesn't seem to accept and parse the **datatype**.  What did I miss or do wrong here?
Thanks for your help

**Full Demo here:**
[Live on Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/o9e7MP4oM)

Comment: Could be related to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73322232/4641116 .  Sehe is awesome.

Comment: From the `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` output, I see that the `enum_` matched, because it is optional, so the `(enum_ | datatype_ | default_)` is done, but then there is still "datatype restriction;" to parse, and the `> ';'` fails because there's nothing to parse the "datatype restriction" before the ";".

Comment: @Eljay.  Thanks for looking into this. ```datatype_ and default_``` are also optional.  So Simple class can have additional enum or datatype or default.  That's what I'm trying to extend.  Currently only enum_ work but datatype_ and default_ don't work.

Comment: No time to look, but from the comments it seems like you want `(-a >> -b >> -c)` instead of `-(a|b|c)`

Comment: @Sehe.  Echoing what Eljay said: "Sehe you are awesome".  I was under impression that my individual rule already said parse zero or one so I'm using the | rule.   Thanks again both of you Eljay and Sehe.

Comment: So I'm back :) Just went through the thing and reviewed. Long story short: don't settle for less. Zooming out, I think, instead of just diving in, you should spend the time to get to know the AST/Domain and describe it fully. This prevents you from redoing a lot of work multiple times and/or running into impossibilities. (Cheers @Eljay thanks for the kind words :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I already addressed in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76416623/whats-wrong-with-my-c-boost-spirit-grammar-rules#comment134748344_76416623):

> it seems like you want (-a >> -b >> -c) instead of -(a|b|c)

Indeed, running your program [prints](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/o9e7MP4oM)

```
 -> EXPECTED ";" in line:3
       Class Simple my_value datatype restriction;
                             ^--- here
```

On the one hand, [I'm thrilled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76375924/_/76385728#76385728:%7E:text=It%27s%20just%20a%20shame%20that%20all%20my%20pretty%20error%20handling%20code%20is%20not%20firing) that now my VeryPretty™ error reporting got a chance to shine, but clearly you wanted to change

```
simple_    = lit("Simple") >> id_ >> optlit >> (enum_ | datatype_ | default_);
```

To

```
simple_    = lit("Simple") >> id_ >> optlit >> enum_ >> datatype_ >> default_;
```

Indeed, changing that around [prints](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/fhG488Ezh):

```xml
<task>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>caption</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>columns</identifier>
      <literal>Column Name</literal>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>my_value</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <word>restriction</word>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>def_value</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <default>
        <num>0</num>
      </default>
    </simple>
  </class>
</task>
```

However several things seem out of order. For one the appearance of `"word"` in the XML seems odd, since `Simple` does not *contain* such a member. It does seem like the implementation details are leaking out in the XML.

I can guess that this is caused by the lack of control that is, itself, caused by ambiguous types:

```
using Id       = std::string;
using Literal  = std::string;
using Datatype = std::string;
using Default  = std::string;
```

Choosing **identical** types for domain datatypes is **fine**, but it breaks down when you try to use the C++ type system to enforce domain logic. Specifically, we use overload resolution to pick what XML to generate for an AST node.

You may note that I had already realized this conundrum in my original sketch, which is why you see the overload generating for `std::string` take a disambiguator `kind`:

```
void apply(Node parent, std::string const& s, char const* kind) const {
```

And there it is that we run into a different code smell:

```
if (s != "") {
    named_child(parent, kind).text().set(s.c_str());
}
```

I know I didn't have the conditional there. And the conditional suffers the same problem as I just described: it is blind to the domain semantics of the "thing" being serialized. Some strings might be "present" and need to be serialized even if empty (e.g. consider when a default value is the empty string, dropping the node entirely may change the meaning).

Instead, you want to **express** intent/semantics in the AST itself.

### Expressive AST

Let's create distinct string types.

> *I showed [one approach in the first Live Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76375924/how-to-parse-code-definition-text-into-xml-structure-with-the-latest-boost-spiri/76385728#76385728:%7E:text=Here%27s%20a%20Live%20Demo%20printing%20the%20raw%20AST%20for%20the%20sample%20input) before. I "cleverly" omitted that hack from the answer because it [wasn't essential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76375924/how-to-parse-code-definition-text-into-xml-structure-with-the-latest-boost-spiri/76385728#comment134694978_76385728) to the final solution, and also because that solution using inheritance violates [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) as well as risks surprises ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66497269/85371)).*

So let's do another approach. Still using a hack to avoid writing lots of code, but without the issues described:

```
template <typename> struct flavour_hack : std::char_traits<char> {};
template <typename Tag>
    using String = std::basic_string<char, flavour_hack<Tag> >;

using Id       = String<struct TagId>;
using Literal  = String<struct TagLiteral>;
using Datatype = String<struct TagDatatype>;
using Default  = String<struct TagDefault>;
```

Yes these are fully standard C++ strings, but distinct from eachother. Nice. Now the above overload can be split into different overloads, dropping the `kind` parameter since that information is now part of the AST type:

```
void apply(Node parent, Ast::Id const& id) const {
    named_child(parent, "identifier").text().set(id.c_str());
}

void apply(Node parent, Ast::Literal const& literal) const {
    named_child(parent, "literal").text().set(literal.c_str());
}

void apply(Node parent, Ast::Datatype const& datatype) const {
    named_child(parent, "datatype").text().set(datatype.c_str());
}

void apply(Node parent, Ast::Default const& default_) const {
    named_child(parent, "default").text().set(default_.c_str());
}
```

What about the optional strings? Well I'm glad you asked. And I'm glad hypothetical you phrased the question accurately: *optional strings are just strings, that are optional*. It's easy to express the semantics in C++:

```
struct Simple : Base {
    Enum                    enumeration;
    std::optional<Datatype> datatype;
    std::optional<Default>  def;
};
```

What's more, now I can probably stop being lazy about the enumeration as well. Before, I just decided/assumed on your behalf that empty enumerations couldn't occur. Let's not, just to drive home the point about domain semantics:

```
struct Simple : Base {
    std::optional<Enum>     enumeration;
    std::optional<Datatype> datatype;
    std::optional<Default>  def;
};
```

And fixing the rule for enumeration:

```
enum_ = lit("enumeration") >> '(' >> -(id_ % ',') > ')';
```

Moving the optionality to the parent rule smooths out the mapping of rules to their bound attributes:

```
simple_    = lit("Simple") >> id_ >> optlit >> -enum_ >> -datatype_ >> -default_;
enum_      = lit("enumeration") >> '(' >> -(id_ % ',') > ')';
datatype_  = lit("datatype") >> id_;
default_   = lit("Default") >> alnum;
```

With these tweaks, we get **[Live Demo](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/x4cfYosGn)** for

```
Class Simple A;
Class Simple B "Column Name";
Class Simple C datatype restriction;
Class Simple D Default 0;
Class Simple E enumeration() Default 0;
Class Simple F enumeration() Default "not_a_number";
```

The output:

```xml
<task>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>A</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>B</identifier>
      <literal>Column Name</literal>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>C</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <datatype>restriction</datatype>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>D</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <default>0</default>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>E</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <default>0</default>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>F</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <default>"not_a_number"</default>
    </simple>
  </class>
</task>
```

### Remaining Loose Ends

I've ignored this bit:

```
// TODO FIXME
//void apply(Node parent, Default const& d) const {
    //if (d != "") {
        //auto def_ = named_child(parent, "default");
        //named_child(def_, "num").text().set(d.c_str());
    //}
//}
```

I did so, because it opens an entirely new can of worms. The "arbitrary" appearance of a `num` XML element tells me that your language has a type system with ditto literals. And that the parser expression

```
default_ = -(lit("Default") >> alnum)
```

was likely woefully underspecified. Do yourself a favor and don't settle for sloppy a solution. Instead, just model what you know to be true and enjoy a life without unnecessary complexity and hard-to-maintain code. E.g.:

```
using Number = double;
using Value  = boost::variant<Literal, Number, Id>;

struct Simple : Base {
    std::optional<Enum>     enumeration;
    std::optional<Datatype> datatype;
    std::optional<Value>    def;
};
```

With ditto

```
value_     = literal_ | number_ | id_;
number_    = double_;
default_   = lit("Default") >> value_;
```

And some tweaks to `XML` generator:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/xd8dfd8rM)**

```
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG 1
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <optional>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace Ast {
    using boost::recursive_wrapper;

    template <typename> struct flavour_hack : std::char_traits<char> {};
    template <typename Tag>
        using String = std::basic_string<char, flavour_hack<Tag> >;

    using Id       = String<struct TagId>;
    using Literal  = String<struct TagLiteral>;
    using Datatype = String<struct TagDatatype>;
    struct Base {
        Id      id;
        Literal literal;
    };

    using Enum = std::vector<Id>;

    using Number = double;
    using Value  = boost::variant<Literal, Number, Id>;

    struct Simple : Base {
        std::optional<Enum>     enumeration;
        std::optional<Datatype> datatype;
        std::optional<Value>    default_;
    };

    struct Complex;
    struct Container;

    using Class = boost::variant<   
        Simple,                     
        recursive_wrapper<Complex>, 
        recursive_wrapper<Container>
    >;

    using Classes = std::vector<Class>;
    struct Container : Base { Class   element; };
    struct Complex   : Base { Classes members; };

    using Task = std::vector<Class>;
} // namespace Ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Simple,    id, literal, enumeration, datatype, default_);
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Complex,   id, literal, members)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Container, id, literal, element)

namespace Parser {
    template <typename It> struct Task : qi::grammar<It, Ast::Task()> {
        Task() : Task::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;

            start = skip(space)[task_];

            // lexemes:
            id_      = raw[alpha >> *('_' | alnum)];
            literal_ = '"' > *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) > '"';

            auto optlit = copy(literal_ | attr(std::string(" "))); // weird, but okay

            task_      = *class_ > eoi;
            type_      = simple_ | complex_ | container_;
            class_     = lit("Class") > type_ > ';';
            simple_    = lit("Simple") >> id_ >> optlit >> -enum_ >> -datatype_ >> -default_;
            complex_   = lit("Complex") >> id_ >> optlit >> '(' >> *type_ >> ')';
            container_ = lit("Container") >> id_ >> optlit >> '(' >> type_ > ')';
            enum_      = lit("enumeration") >> '(' >> -(id_ % ',') > ')';
            datatype_  = lit("datatype") >> id_;
            value_     = literal_ | number_ | id_;
            number_    = double_;
            default_   = lit("Default") >> value_;

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (task_)(class_)(type_)(simple_)(complex_)(container_)(enum_)(datatype_)
                (default_)(id_)(literal_)(value_)(number_)
            )
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Task()> start;

        using Skipper = qi::space_type;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Task(), Skipper>      task_;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Class(), Skipper>     class_, type_;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Simple(), Skipper>    simple_;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Complex(), Skipper>   complex_;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Container(), Skipper> container_;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Enum(), Skipper>      enum_;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Datatype(), Skipper>  datatype_;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Value(), Skipper>     default_;

        // lexemes:
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Id()>      id_;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Literal()> literal_;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Value()>   value_;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Number()>  number_;
    };
}

#include <pugixml.hpp>
namespace Generate {
    using namespace Ast;

    struct XML {
        using Node = pugi::xml_node;

        // callable for variant visiting:
        template <typename T> void operator()(Node parent, T const& node) const { apply(parent, node); }

    private:
        template <typename... Ts>
        void apply(Node parent, boost::variant<Ts...> const& v) const {
            using std::placeholders::_1;
            boost::apply_visitor(std::bind(*this, parent, _1), v);
        }

        void apply(Node parent, Ast::Number const& num) const {
            named_child(parent, "num").text().set(num);
        }

        void apply(Node parent, Ast::Id const& id) const {
            named_child(parent, "identifier").text().set(id.c_str());
        }

        void apply(Node parent, Ast::Literal const& literal) const {
            named_child(parent, "literal").text().set(literal.c_str());
        }

        void apply(Node parent, Ast::Datatype const& datatype) const {
            named_child(parent, "datatype").text().set(datatype.c_str());
        }

        template <typename T> void apply(Node parent, std::optional<T> const& opt) const {
            if (opt)
                apply(parent, *opt);
        }

        void apply(Node parent, Simple const& s) const {
            auto simple = named_child(parent, "simple");
            apply(simple, s.id);
            apply(simple, s.literal);
            apply(simple, s.enumeration);
            apply(simple, s.datatype);
            if (s.default_.has_value()) {
                apply(named_child(simple, "default"), *s.default_);
            }
        }

        void apply(Node parent, Enum const& e) const {
            auto enum_ = named_child(parent, "enumeration");
            for (auto& v : e)
                named_child(enum_, "word").text().set(v.c_str());
        }

        void apply(Node parent, Complex const& c) const {
            auto complex_ = named_child(parent, "complex");
            apply(complex_, c.id);
            apply(complex_, c.literal);
            for (auto& m : c.members)
                apply(complex_, m);
        }

        void apply(Node parent, Container const& c) const {
            auto cont = named_child(parent, "container");
            apply(cont, c.id);
            apply(cont, c.literal);
            apply(cont, c.element);
        }

        void apply(Node parent, Task const& t) const {
            auto task = named_child(parent, "task");
            for (auto& c : t)
                apply(task.append_child("class"), c);
        }

    private:
        Node named_child(Node parent, std::string const& name) const {
            auto child = parent.append_child();
            child.set_name(name.c_str());
            return child;
        }
    };
} // namespace Generate

int main() { 
    using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;
    static const Parser::Task<It> p;
    static const Generate::XML to_xml;

    for (std::string_view input :
    {
        R"(Class Simple A;
    Class Simple B "Column Name";
    Class Simple C datatype restriction;
    Class Simple D enumeration() Default NaN;
    Class Simple E Default -Inf;
    Class Simple F Default 42;
    Class Simple G Default 7.8e-10;
    Class Simple H Default "not a number";
    Class Simple I Default SomeIdentifier_3;
        )"
    }) //
    {
        try {
            Ast::Task t;

            if (qi::parse(begin(input), end(input), p, t)) {
                pugi::xml_document doc;
                to_xml(doc.root(), t);
                doc.print(std::cout, "  ", pugi::format_default);
                std::cout << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << " -> INVALID" << std::endl;
            }
        } catch (qi::expectation_failure<It> const& ef) {
            auto f    = begin(input);
            auto p    = ef.first - input.begin();
            auto bol  = input.find_last_of("\r\n", p) + 1;
            auto line = std::count(f, f + bol, '\n') + 1;
            auto eol  = input.find_first_of("\r\n", p);

            std::cerr << " -> EXPECTED " << ef.what_ << " in line:" << line << "\n"
                << input.substr(bol, eol - bol) << "\n"
                << std::setw(p - bol) << ""
                << "^--- here" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Printing

```xml
<task>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>A</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>B</identifier>
      <literal>Column Name</literal>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>C</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <datatype>restriction</datatype>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>D</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <enumeration />
      <default>
        <num>nan</num>
      </default>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>E</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <default>
        <num>-inf</num>
      </default>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>F</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <default>
        <num>42</num>
      </default>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>G</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <default>
        <num>7.7999999999999999e-10</num>
      </default>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>H</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <default>
        <literal>not a number</literal>
      </default>
    </simple>
  </class>
  <class>
    <simple>
      <identifier>I</identifier>
      <literal> </literal>
      <default>
        <identifier>SomeIdentifier_3</identifier>
      </default>
    </simple>
  </class>
</task>
```

Comment: I'm enjoy reading your explanations.  It helps me a lot in exploring and learning C++ and boost.  With my limited knowledge on this subject, I can only explore or do a certain task.  You seem to know these things inside out so it every easy for you to come up with alternative routes when problem occurs.  I do appreciate your willingness of taking time share your wisdom,  and teach us newbie in this forum.  I'm very sure I'll have more question once I get the full document of the code definition.  Hopefully with these lessons, I can move along and getting it done for my team. :)

Comment: (I just noticed I forgot to remove the `.empty()` check on generating XML for enumerations)

Comment: _"You seem to know these things inside out so it every easy for you to come up with alternative routes when problem occurs"_ - The very definition of experience. It's why I feel I can permit myself to put guidance in somewhat opinionated terms ("do yourself a favour"). I know because I've learnt that lesson the hard way, many times over. I try to back it up with reasoning and links to the principles involved, so the seed can fall on fertile grounds. That's how we learn. Cheers!

Comment: What if `enum_ >> datatype_ >> default_` are three mutually exclusive arms (and all are optional)?  What if each can appear zero-or-once, and they can appear in any order?

Comment: @Eljay it's all [documented](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator.html) :)  So to get zero-once in any order you can say `-(a ^ b ^ c)`. Three mutually exclusives is almost what OP accidentally wrote (`-(a|b|c)` instead of `(-a|-b|-c)`)

Comment: @sehe.  Since I'm using the latest boost version (1.82,0), do you recommend using QI or X3 for this project?  They both new for me to learn anyway.  I just don't want to spend time upgrading this to X3 in the future.

Comment: I think Qi is more mature and has fewer surprises (especially surrounding automatic propagation). However, X3 is a lot quicker to compile. If you are prepared to do a lot manual massaging with semantic actions anyways, X3 might be easier, since they're bit more natural now.